# Cant login to this Expense Manager found In GitHub

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I was searching for an expense manager that handles income and expense of my shop finally I got one from the GitHub but I imported the database and I installed it in the local server but when I try to log in I cannot login to the system, Even I try to change the code in user login session some way I just logged in by disabling a method in profile function on user controller but after login I can only see the account and about section [this is the gitHub link of that project](https://github.com/web-project-builder/expense-management-codeigniter-adminlte-php)

is there anyone that used this code from GitHub or fixed the error?? of login please help
[this is the image of expense manager while I logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkGuw.png)
Anyone, please help!!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/web-project-builder/expense-management-codeigniter-adminlte-php/issues

This is the best place to find answers about this software.

Edit the index.php file found in the ExpenseManager software's root directory and place `session_start();` at the top, inside the `<?php` tag, before the comments, just like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Also see this Evernote entry, as it may help you with what is happening for you:
[HOWTO Fix Expense Management CodeIgniter PHP from Github](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s158/client/snv?noteGuid=5dc1e38b-db14-42bf-a873-5ea28e1fc9f6&noteKey=3dfffa95099400de&sn=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.evernote.com%2Fshard%2Fs158%2Fsh%2F5dc1e38b-db14-42bf-a873-5ea28e1fc9f6%2F3dfffa95099400de&title=HOWTO%2BFix%2BExpense%2BManagement%2BCodeIgniter%2BPHP%2Bfrom%2BGithub)